# aligning xticks in matplotlib plot with lines and boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

i am unable to get the following plot to align properly along the x-axis. specifically, i want to plot a horizontal line representing the last value in the dataframe on top of a boxplot which describes the full sample. here is the code. currently i have commented out the line which would plot the boxplot

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', '2/1/2018')

data = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(32)}, index=index)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,3))

ax.hlines(data.iloc[-1],xmin=pd.RangeIndex(stop=len(list(data.columns)))+.15,xmax=pd.RangeIndex(stop=len(list(data.columns)))+.85,
                  **{'linewidth':1.5})

# ax.boxplot(data.values)
ax.set_xticks(pd.RangeIndex(stop=len(list(data.columns)))+0.5)
ax.set_xticklabels(list(data.columns), rotation=0)

ax.tick_params(axis='x',length=5, bottom=True)
```

here is the output from the above (so far so good)

[image: without the boxplot]

if i uncomment the line from above, the code would produce this, which is misaligned:

[image: with the boxplot]

any tips for how to get them to line up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have a very clear opinion about the boxplot to be positionned at x=0.5. But you forgot to tell the boxplot about that.

```
ax.boxplot(data.values, positions=[0.5])
```

[image]